# AWS develop on containerized lambda but push to non-containerized prod using gitlab CI/CD

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci

I'm new to docker containers and CI/CD so I was wondering if I could get some help.

I want to use Dockerized AWS lambda functions in development and testing. But I don't want a dockerized lambda running on an EC2 for production. Instead, I would like my code to be pushed directly to AWS Lambda and access it there.

Is there a way using gitlab CI/CD to take my lambda code and push it to AWS lambda?

Comment: Lambda and EC2 are exclusive from one another. You can run containers on the lambda runtime, no EC2 is involved. I'm not sure exactly what your question is, though. What exactly are you having troubles with? What have you tried/read so far?

Comment: @sytech On the [AWS docs for creating containerized lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)
it says "You can package your Lambda function code and dependencies as a container image, using tools such as the Docker CLI. You can then upload the image to your container registry hosted on Amazon ECR"
From my understanding the ECR then creates EC2 instances that run the container image. I'm wondering if I can get my code outside the container for production and push it directly to lambda using gitlab CI/CD instead of pushing it ECR